# Tomcat Server testing 404 Not Found Error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, server, http-status-code-404

I wanted to run a „TestServlet.java” file to try out my first Tomcat server connection. I have uploaded my maps to my repository to show you my actual project: https://github.com/Capkit/Servlet-testing

The point is:
I have a TestServlet.java file (in test package) – I complied it to the „classes” map: „TestServlet.class”.
I have a Deployment Description: web.xml file.
The desired action is that if I type the URL „localhost:8080/TestServlet/mutasd (as in the web.xml), my TestServlet  file shows the html file on the web page. But instead of that, I got a 404 error message.

I if run simply localhost:8080, the tomcat server appears, and I can sign is to the manager app too. What could be the problem?

I tried to change the port number, but it did not help. Do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your servlet-mapping set up with this URL pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/mutasd</url-pattern
```

So your tomcat instance should be available at this URL:

http://localhost:8080/mutasd

(I think you have an extra directory listed in your post)

Edit: The above applies if you put your WEB-INF directory into webapps/ROOT. If you put it in webapps/TestServlet, then indeed your app should be working on localhost:8080/TestServlet/mutasd .

If that doesn't work, take a look at the log file logs/catalina.out. There should be some messages when you start up tomcat about deploying your servlet.

That reminds me, you can receive the errors you've seen if you don't deploy your servlet. To deploy, just restart Tomcat after you've copied the files into tomcat's webapps directory. You can also use Tomcat's manager app to deploy/undeploy as well. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html

Comment: Yes, I added this servlet-mapping to the web.xml but I used this URL: http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/mutasd. 
I tried http://localhost:8080/mutasd as you wrote, but it did not work too. 
What extra directory do you think? 
Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I assumed you put your WEB-INF directory in the webapps/ROOT directory. Check the name of the directory that you put it in. If you put it in webapps/TestServlet, then indeed your app should be working on localhost:8080/TestServlet/mutasd . I just tried it myself with your code, and it worked. I'll edit my response.

Answer (score 0):

I've cloned your repo and your app runs Ok on my Tomcat server. However, i'm running it by copying the project folder directly to Tomcat installation webapps folder.

Are you running the project on an IDE (Eclipse, etc.)?

Comment: Maybe my project folder is in wrong place within my computer or I have somewhat problem with my library structure. I have no more idea, it still not work. 

No, I have not tried to run this project in any IDE yet.
Thank's your reply!